# cpp syntax for CLICK modules

Tags: c++, c++11

I was just trying to work on some "click" cpp modules.
I came accross this syntax

```
class SimpleQueue : public Element, public Storage { public:
SimpleQueue() CLICK_COLD;
int configure(Vector<String>&, ErrorHandler*) CLICK_COLD;
```

I was wondering what is this syntax "**CLICK_COLD**"?

https://github.com/kohler/click/blob/master/elements/standard/simplequeue.hh

This is just one file. But there is more than one file which has this **"CLICK_COLD"** used every where. Not sure what is this syntax in cpp?

In general I wanted to understand what is **XYZ_YYY** after any method or constructor mean in cpp?

Comment: Why is this question tagged in so many different languages? Revise your question please, and remove unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Preprocessor Directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).
You can find out how it's defined in **config.h**:

```
/* Define macro for cold (rarely used) functions. */
#if __GNUC__ < 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 3)
# define CLICK_COLD /* nothing */
#else
# define CLICK_COLD __attribute__((cold))
#endif
```

What it does is, if the compiler's version is high enough to support [Attribute Syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html), then use `__attribute__((cold))`, or otherwise do nothing.

`__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` tells [the version of the compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) you're using.

`cold` is one of the [common function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html), described as follows:

> The cold attribute on functions is used to inform the compiler that the function is unlikely to be executed. The function is optimized for size rather than speed and on many targets it is placed into a special subsection of the text section so all cold functions appear close together, improving code locality of non-cold parts of program. The paths leading to calls of cold functions within code are marked as unlikely by the branch prediction mechanism. It is thus useful to mark functions used to handle unlikely conditions, such as perror, as cold to improve optimization of hot functions that do call marked functions in rare occasions.

To sum up, every function with `CLICK_COLD` is rarely used, helping the compiler optimize so.

Comment: Thanks @Dean. It was helpful

Comment: can you please let me know from where did you get this?

"The cold attribute on functions is used to inform the compiler that the function is unlikely to be executed. The function is optimized for size ...."

Comment: @YOGI I've just updated my answer with the link to the attribute description page.